# Resurrection Remix Google Pixel vendor mismatch fix

Tags: android, google-pixel

This isn't a question so much as it is an answer I spent HOURS trying to find. I flashed RR on my Google Pixel and things were fine, however, the vendor was mismatched and even though I tried my best to flash the vendor it kept failing.

The fix?

When flashing the vendor, at least for me, it kept failing because it seemed to misname the vendor destination is was going to. So I did it individually to "fastboot flash vendor_a vendor.img" and "fastboot flash vendor_b vendor.img" respectively for the a and b slots. That did the trick! Hope this helps anyone as frustrated as I was.

Comment: Hi!  Perhaps post this as a question, and then a separate answer, for people looking for this.  That will keep the site consistent.